# Visual studio code editor shows errors(red lines under codes) in my sass codes

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, frontend, web-deployment

My sass codes in vs code have errors. Sounds like vs code doesn't support sass codes. I opened the project in Atom and it worked properly. In vs code works also but it shows red lines under some of the codes.
As you see in the picture it has errors. How can I fix it?

html
[image]

cass

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your HTML structure for same?

Comment: Yes of course. I uploaded it to my question.

Comment: When you hover over the lines what error does it show?

Comment: Your code is definetivily correct! Are you sure you are writing in a (the) `SCSS` file ... that's a typical error if your try to write your SCSS code in a (the) open `CSS` file ... ;-)